# Does sequence of "means" of partial sums of a sequence in $\ell^2$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Namely, if $x\in \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, and $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$. Does the sequence $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}s_n$ converge. I have shown that its a bounded sequence, but I'm unsure if it converges. It looks very similar to a Cesaro sum, but I don't know how to handle this sequence. To me it seems that this sequence tends towards $0$, but I haven't had much luck establishing this so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, pick an $m$ such that

$$\sum_{k = m}^\infty \lvert x_k\rvert^2 < \frac{\varepsilon^2}{4}.$$

For $n \geqslant m$, we then have

$$\frac{\lvert s_n\rvert}{\sqrt{n}} \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k = 1}^{m-1} \lvert x_k\rvert + \frac{\sqrt{n-m+1}}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\sum_{k = m}^n \lvert x_k\rvert^2} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k = 1}^{m-1} \lvert x_k\rvert + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$

For large enough $n$, the first term on the right is smaller than $\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$s_n =\sum_{1\leq j\leq n} 1\cdot x_j \leq \sqrt{n} \sqrt{\sum_{1\leq j\leq n}  x_j^2 }$$ hence $$\frac{s_n}{\sqrt{n}} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{1\leq j\leq n}  x_j^2 } \leq\sqrt{\sum_{1\leq j}  x_j^2 } <\infty$$